# NSDateFormatter not formatting (returning nil)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I have a date string, for example:

```
2012-04-09T23:57:44.070Z
```

My date format is:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
```

But it's returning nil. What's wrong with my date format?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to be so aggressive about escaping `-` and `:`.  Also, your seconds characters are wrong.  You should be using:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];

NSLog(@"%@", [f dateFromString:@"2012-04-09T23:57:44.070Z"]);
```

This logs:

```
2012-04-09 23:57:44 +0000
```

If you don't set the timezone on the date formatter, it's going to assume you mean whatever time zone the device is in right now, and *not* the GMT timezone (which is what the `Z` is implying).

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what if you want to do it the other way around? How would I get a date object from this string: 2012-04-09 23:57:44 +0000   THANKS!

Comment: @RafaelMoreira `NSDateFormatter` has a `-dateFromString:` method.

Comment: I know that. I meant what the format of the date formatter would be. I've tried [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"]; but it doesn't work. I've also tried with only one Z and ZZ but with no success.